# JQuery capturar el evento de varios links

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, jquery-ui

tengo una función en jquery, que cuando selecciono un checkbox hago una llamada ajax para recoger unos datos mediante post y los muestro en una tabla (hasta aquí me funciona), ahora lo que intento hacer es con los datos devueltos crear una tabla html de "links" i al hacer click en el link capturar en el evento ja que la idea es cojer esa información y pasarla a otra tabla html.

Para ello tengo este código, como digo me construye la tabla html con los "a href" a partir del json devuelto, lo que no me funciona es capturar el evento del "a href" para yo hacer la acción correspondiente.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("a").click(function(){
            alert("You've clicked the link.");
        });

        $(".form-check-input").click(function(){
            var favorite = [];
            $.each($("input[name='foodType']:checked"), function(){
                favorite.push($(this).val());
            });

            var editUrl = '{{ route("api.aliments.searchByFoodType", ':value') }}';
            editUrl = editUrl.replace(':value', 'type='+ favorite);

            $.ajax({
                url:  editUrl,
                method: 'POST'
            }).done(function (data) {

                $("#alimentsMaster").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();

                $.each( data, function( key, value ) {

                    $('#alimentsMaster').append('<tr><td>'+ value['name']+'</td>' +
                        '<td><a href=\"#\">Click</a></td>' +
                        '</tr>');


                });

            });
        });

    });
```